# How to connect external app SQLite database in my android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app called `Mi Band Master` that connects to MiBand 2, this app has an open database in this path: `/sdcard/mibandmaster/db.sqlite`.

I want to make an app that connects to that database for an activity & heartrate study.

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [How to ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are always encouraged to ask a question regarding a specific issue but presenting a requirement without any research and failed/half failed attempts will get you downvotes and flags. Do some research, attempt solution post a specific question if you face a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/android/com.myapp/databases/mydatabase.db" ); 
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
db.getVersion();
db.execSQL("Select 1"); //for test
```

Comment: It doesn't work :(. However, thanks for answering ;)

Comment: Do you check permissions in the manifest file? `<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest> `